# Query specific table in C# Visual Studio database

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Visual Studio MVC3 and trying to connect to a database. I have my connection string in the web.config file:

> add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
>   User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

However, the server has multiple tables. How/where will I specify which table to use when querying the database?

EDIT:
For example, I am looking at [this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). How does the application differentiate between the tables to display data? When you call  `return View(db.Students.ToList())` as in the example in the link, how does the application know to look in the student table and not in the enrollment table?

Comment: You mean multiple _tables_ or multiple _databases_?  The table is specified in the `SELECT` statement (or your Entity model).  The database is specified in the connection string (`myDatabase` in your example)

Comment: Referencing tables is a part of a particular query (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc.), and not a component of the connection string. If you need help with a query or command statement, please include it in your question.

Comment: Edited. Please see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the application differentiate between the tables to display
>   data? When you call `return View(db.Students.ToList())` as in the
>   example in the link, how does the application know to look in the
>   student table and not in the enrollment table?

The `db.Students` part comes from Entity Framework.

Read the "Creating the Database Context" section in the link that you posted.
You will find the following code there:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

This sets up the database context, which is basically Entity Framework's "setup", from where it knows which C# class it has to map to database tables.

So `db.Students` (from your question) is actually a `DbSet<Student>`.

Entity Framework's default convention looks like this: it tries to map a class to a table with the same name.
Usually, it would map the `Student` class to a table named `Students` (pluralized), but you can change/override these conventions...which they also did in this example, in this line:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

This is also explained in the tutorial, directly under the above code.
Quote from the tutorial:

> This code creates a `DbSet` property for each entity set. In Entity
>   Framework terminology, an *entity set* typically corresponds to a
>   database table, and an *entity* corresponds to a row in the table.
>
> The statement in the `OnModelCreating` method prevents table names from
>   being pluralized. If you didn't do this, the generated tables would be
>   named `Students`, `Courses`, and `Enrollments`. Instead, the table names
>   will be `Student`, `Course`, and `Enrollment`. Developers disagree about
>   whether table names should be pluralized or not. This tutorial uses
>   the singular form, but the important point is that you can select
>   whichever form you prefer by including or omitting this line of code.